how to move on specific page when user click on mp3 file from file mananger in React Native
I'm working on Music player application , i have created library page where i have local files so i want that when user click on any mp3 in file manager then it asks open with so when i choose my player then it should move on the library -> local files page how i can do that in react native.
i'm not able to get the status that from where i'm coming or launching the app to do the need full.
is there anyone who can help me with this please.
